# JSON request behavior to AllowGet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

This is my controller code :

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult ImportFilesCombined(ImportFilesModel importFile,ImportFilesModel2 importFile2)
    {
        ImportFiles importFiles = new ImportFiles();
        ImportFiles2 importFiles2 = new ImportFiles2();



        string folderpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadFilePath"];

        string filename = "*";
        string[] fileList = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderpath, filename);//getting the file names from the folder as an array

        List<ImportFilesModel> inputFiles = new List<ImportFilesModel>(fileList.Length);//making a list of same number of elements as the number of files            
        inputFiles = importFiles.GetImportFilesDetails();
                    foreach (string str in fileList)
        {
            ImportFilesModel inputFile = new ImportFilesModel();
            inputFile.FileName = Path.GetFileName(str);
            inputFile.FileSelected = false;
            inputFiles.Add(inputFile);
        }
        List<ImportFilesModel2> inputFiles2 = new List<ImportFilesModel2>();
        inputFiles2 = importFiles2.GetImportFilesDetails2();

        var tuple = new Tuple<List<AetnaCoventryMigration.Model.ImportFilesModel>, List<AetnaCoventryMigration.Model.ImportFilesModel2>>(inputFiles, inputFiles2);

        return Json(tuple, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);        
    }
```

I am getting the error :

> This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

I have already allowed it in my return statement, but still the error is coming.

Comment: Your method is probably throwing an exception before the return statement.

Comment: umm , how can I get rid of that?

Comment: I have already set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet then why is that exception being thrown?

Comment: Step through your code line by line in debugger and see if return statement is reached

Comment: no , it is not reaching.

Comment: Where is it failing then?

Comment: Hey , thank you all of you ,I fixed that issue . Now how to access tuple in my view ? (I am passing 2 list of models to the view) Is there a special way to access some property in one of my models.

Comment: Now , I am using this in my view :   model Tuple<ImportFilesModel,ImportFilesModel2>   Can I use the elements of model1 and model2 as model.ImportFilesModel and model.ImportFilesModel2 ?

Comment: Random text is coming on the html page ,like everything but un-formatted , no tables , plain text . Is this a binding problem?

Comment: Start a new question, and close this one if you want answers to the tuple issue.